# Display location from address stored in db

Tags: angular, google-maps, angular5

Let me explain briefly what I do want. I have module that contains 2 pages.
One is for creating new company and the other one is for preview company info + edit that company info.

Everything works fine. Now when I click in my table one of those companies, it opens "edit/IDOFORGANIZATIONHERE" and it displays all of  the information for the clicked organization(company).

Now I need to implement feature for google map to display company's location based on company's address,city,postal code and country.

I have implemented Google Maps successfully.

```
   this.gMapsService.getLatLan('London' )
          .subscribe(
            result => {
                this.__zone.run(() => {
                    this.lat = result.lat();
                    this.lng = result.lng();
                })
            },
            error => console.log(error),
            () => console.log('Geocoding completed!')
          );
```

In my gMapsService I have following

```
  import { Injectable, NgZone } from '@angular/core';
    import { GoogleMapsAPIWrapper } from '@agm/core';
    import { MapsAPILoader } from '@agm/core';
    import { Observable, Observer } from 'rxjs';
    import {} from '@types/googlemaps';

    declare var google: any;

    @Injectable()
    export class GMapsService extends GoogleMapsAPIWrapper{ 
        constructor(private __loader: MapsAPILoader, private __zone: NgZone) {
            super(__loader, __zone);
        }

        getLatLan(address) {
            console.log('Getting Address - ', address);
            let geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
            return Observable.create(observer => {
                geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
                    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                        observer.next(results[0].geometry.location);
                        observer.complete();                    
                    } else {
                        console.log('Error - ', results, ' & Status - ', status);
                        observer.next({});
                        observer.complete();
                    }
                });
            })
        }
    }
```

Now if you take a look at the first snippet its gonna display google map with London city being centered and this also works perfectly.

Now I want to change this string London to be value of company's info such as

```
organization.address
organization.city
organization.postalcode
organization.countryname
```

If I write it like this this.gMapsService.getLatLan(this.address) or
this.gMapsService.getLatLan(organization.address) code successfully compiles but in my console I can see that Address that is being passed is "undefined".

However my address shows fine in my html portion of the web where it says

```
Address: {{organization ? organization.address : ''}}<br>
```

I am now wondering how to turn this text that displays after Address: in the string that needs to be passed along with function getLatLan.

I have tried making

`let fulladdress = organization.address + organization...bla bla`   and passing this.fulladdress but it still displays that address,postal code, city is undefined

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed it on my own, by subscribing data of organization in the function as well, even though it was executed in  `ngOnInit(){}`.

Thanks anyways.